# client PC information from web page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, plugins

I need to create an asp.net web page which shows the client system (PC) information when they access the page. I think i need to use some sort of plug in to get access to client system. But i dont know where to start the things here and how to integrate the plugin with my aspx page?

So to summarize, from my computer if I go to this website and it tells me the memory on my computer, disk space, OS, etc.

Any help will be much appreciated..

EDIT: Yes, i know its not going to happened with simple page. But what about the plugins? Cant i use any plugin which needs to get installed on browser and give me the info i want?

Thank you.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure but I think this could only work in IE and with ActiveX controls, only on Windows...

Comment: Yes, i know its not going to happened with simple page. But what about the plugins? Cant i use any plugin which needs to get installed on browser and give me the info i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to obtain that information without prompting the user, and even then the information would be extremely limited. Allowing a web application to retrieve data from the client would be a serious breach of privacy. With all of the scrutiny surrounding privacy these days, that would be a very slippery slope.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to happen. At least in the honest way, or without the user consent.

Browsers are not meant to give system and user info to any webpage, so even if you find a workaround that will be probably fixed in a next version of the browser (or OS).

The top info you can get is probably the OS, the user-agent, and maybe the screen resolution.

EDIT: One crazy idea, if you can't find an ActiveX/IE combination for that, and you really, really want to get that info and you know your users and the users trust you, you can build a web service that runs on the user side to give the info on your server request (this can help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa389273). Please note that this is not a basic task since you will have to provide security for the users in this web service.